# No Such Element Exception when reading from a file

Tags: java

I understand that this is a commonly asked question, however, I'm not sure why I'm getting the error even after doing research.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class readfile {

    private Scanner x;

    public void openFile(){
        try{
            x = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Oh noes, the file has not been founddd!");
        }
    }

    public void readFile(){
        int n = 0;
        n = Integer.parseInt(x.next()); //n is the integer on the first line that creates boundaries n x n in an array.

        System.out.println("Your array is size ["+ n + "] by [" + n +"]");

        //Create n by n array.
        int[][] array = new int[n][n];

        //While there is an element, assign array[i][j] = the next element.
        while(x.hasNext()){
             for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                 for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                     array[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(x.next());
                     System.out.printf("%d", array[i][j]);
                 }
                System.out.println();
             }
        }
    }

    public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
    }
}
```

I'm reading a text file that contains an adjacency matrix, where the first line indicates how large the matrix will be. ie) line 1 reads 5. Therefore I create a 2d array that is 5x5. The problem I'm having is after I read the file and print it, I get a NoSuchElement Exception. Thanks ahead of time!

Note: I am curious, I've seen that I need to user x.hasNext() when in a loop, so I do not assume there is input when there isn't. However, I've done this. Not sure what the problem is.

Output:

```
Your array is size [7] by [7] 
0110011 
1000000 
1001000 
0010001 
0000001 
1000001 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException 
  at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source) 
  at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source) 
  at readfile.readFile(readfile.java:32) 
  at verticies.main(verticies.java:8)
```

Comment: Output: Your array is size [7] by [7]
0110011
1000000
1001000
0010001
0000001
1000001
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at readfile.readFile(readfile.java:32)
 at verticies.main(verticies.java:8)

Comment: which is line number 32?

Comment: array[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(x.next());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code is reading a whole line as an int, is each of those numbers:

```
0110011 1000000 1001000 0010001 0000001 1000001
```

meant to be the 7 digits forming each row?

If that is the case, you need to split each value into the its component parts for its corresponding sub array.

In which case, use this section of code instead:

```
   while(x.hasNext()){
         for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
             String line = x.next();
             for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                 array[i][j] = line.charAt(j) - '0';
                 System.out.printf("%d", array[i][j]);
             }
            System.out.println();
         }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I cannot figure out how to get this site to print these lines right. The integers 0 and 1 you see are NOT on the same line. They are all on different lines.

Consider it like this: 0110011\n 1000000\n ... etc.

Comment: OK, well that exception is thrown when an Enumeration runs out of elements, I'm not sure that the while loop is required though, you have the nested for loops, which should exhaust the content of your file no?

Comment: You're right about the exhaustion. However, the error persists after I remove the while loop. The error is obviously in within the for loops, as the code will not reach any statements following them.

Comment: See edit, x.next() is reading a line, you need to split the line into individual values.

Comment: I understand what you're doing here, it makes sense. The problem now is I'm receiving an out of bounds exception. String Index Out Of Range: 1. I checked the file, and there is a character at index 1. But it's a space. Each number is separated by a space. I may be able to work around this.

Comment: I created an if statement... if j is not equal to a space, it should print the array, but to no avail. Still having issues. It works if the input file does not contain spaces. Sorry that I didn't clarify this earlier.

Comment: `x.next().trim()` is worth a shot. :)

Comment: You guys are going to be so mad at me. Look at the code I posted. The input file says there exists 7 vertices, where as there are only 6 lines (though each line contains info about the other 7 vertices). I was getting my error because the input lines were not equal to the specified number of vertices!!!!!!!! AAAH!

Comment: Problem solved, happy days.  Reminder: Don't forget to vote and accept answers when you get to a solution.